# Why do Posterior Sampling when we can Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, posterior, resampling

I have just taken a stats course where half of the content was to do with sampling from posterior distributions. However, it was not clear why we were doing this when we could simply perform bootstrap resampling. And I've heard about how we want i.i.d. samples, but I can't see how bootstrapping is any worse than posterior sampling in this regard.

Would anyone be able to explain why we care about posterior sampling so much? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Bayesian approach offers the opportunity to specify a prior distribution which will be reflected, with due influence, in the posterior distribution.

Comment: This search may be of interest: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bayesian+bootstrap

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @BruceET, but let's say that we have no prior information so would have to use an uninformative prior. Bayesian methods offer no particular advantage there, especially with large datasets.

Comment: Even with no prior information, it sometimes makes sense to take a Bayesian approach using a flat or non-informative prior distribution. A Bayes interval estimate (credible interval) is a probability statement about the experiment at hand, while a frequentist confidence interval is often interpreted as a statement about similar future situations., // In a binomial setting, you may want to read about the Jeffries interval arising from a Bayesian setting with no prior knowledge, but having useful properties interpreted as a frequentist CI [see Wikipedia on binomial CIs.]

Comment: Awesome, thank you again for that. I totally get that Bayesian credible intervals have some useful properties, however, I still don't see why sampling from that posterior is any better than resampling from the data. For example, with a million coin flips, why sample from a Bernoulli with p sampled from that Jeffries method's posterior rather than resampling from the actually observed coin flips?